# Deploy multiple applications in DevOps pipeline independently (or) separately?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

At the moment below is our pipeline design. We have App "A" and App "B". At the moment we are doing the Build and deploying the Application A & B using the same pipeline.

I am pretty new to Azure DevOps Pipeline and can I get some thoughts or help on how we can design the deployment of the apps separately !

**Ask**: The plan is to separate the Application deployment or split the pipeline into separate deployments for each specific application ( A & B). How can we do that ?

I am referring and learning from sources for example: https://blog.bitsrc.io/separating-build-and-release-pipelines-for-effective-devops-2b0ad5b74af1

But can I get more help on understanding below case ?

- Build Stage
- Deploy to Dev/Test Stage

  - Deploy  App A
  - Deploy  App B
  - Deploy  App C
- Deploy to Acceptance Stage

  - Deploy  App A
  - Deploy  App B
  - Deploy  App C
- Deploy to Production Stage

  - Deploy  App A
  - Deploy  App B
  - Deploy  App C

Comment: What is the detailed question or error you are facing now when trying to configure the pipelines?

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT , tried to update my question , if it makes more sense now , just we are brainstorming how we can seperate 2 apps which are now deployed by a single pipeline into seperate deployments.

Comment: Are the code files of App "A" and App "B" stored in the same repository, or in two different repositories? @Learning_Learning

Comment: Same repository @BrightRan-MSFT. And the pipeline trigger is:  include : master / release/*/prod.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, each deploy Stage in a pipeline should target to a specified environment, or to a particular resource (such as VM, Kubernetes, etc..) added into the environment.

The target environments or resources generally are the destinations to deploy the Apps.

You also can deploy the Apps to different services that are not added as resources into the environments by using the pipeline tasks related to the services.

For more details, you can reference the following documentations:

- [**Create a multistage pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/create-multistage-pipeline?view=azure-devops)
- [**Deploy apps to environments**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops)

---